# Gaussian Blobs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, blob, gaussian, contrast

I am trying to produce Gaussian blobs of different intensities (black, gray, white) and contrasts but then, which parameter am I supposed to change in the code below?

Many thanks in advance!

```
imSize = 300;                           % image size: n X n
lamda = 10;                             % wavelength (number of pixels per cycle)
theta = 15;                              % grating orientation
sigma = 50;

imSize = 300;
% make linear ramp
X = 1:imSize;                           % X is a vector from 1 to imageSize
X0 = (X / imSize) - .5;                 % rescale X -> -.5 to .5
[Xm Ym] = meshgrid(X0, X0);
s = sigma / imSize;  

gauss = exp( -(((Xm.^2)+(Ym.^2)) ./ (2* s^2)) ); % formula for 2D gaussian
%%%%%%% NEW VARIABLES
trim = .005;                             % trim off gaussian values smaller than this
gauss(gauss < trim) = 0;                 % trim around edges (for 8-bit colour displays)

imagesc( gauss, [-1 1] );                        % display
colormap gray(256);
axis off; axis image;     % use gray colormap
```

Comment: Don't you get the expected result when you do - `figure,imshow(gauss)`, if I understood your concept of "blobs" correctly?

Comment: Hi many thanks for the reply! But what I get when I do figure,imshow(gauss) is a change in the background intensity. I would like to make a manipulation that will keep the background at the gray level but change the luminance of the Gaussian blob itself (dark gray on the gray background, white or black on the gray background etc)

Comment: So basically, the question is, how can I get the y axis range between 0 and -1, rather than 0 and 1... or at any other contrasts, i.e. 0 and 0.5 or 0. and -0.5 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these options -

```
gauss = 2*(gauss-0.5); %%// For a range of [-1 1];
imagesc( gauss, [-1 1] );
```

Or

```
gauss = gauss/2; %%// For a range of [0 0.5];
imagesc( gauss, [0 0.5] );
```

Or

```
gauss = 0.5*(gauss-1); %%// For a range of [-0.5 0];
imagesc( gauss, [-0.5 0] );
```

Comment: Yes I realised that, too. Or gauss = -1*(gauss); %%// For a range of [-1 1]; imagesc( gauss, [-1 1] ); does work for a black blob on a gray background, too.

Comment: It's all about shifting the range accordingly! :)